# If Downcasting Should Be Avoided, What Should I Do?

Tags: java, casting, subclass

have the following interface class:

```
public interface IGameObject {

    String gameObjectID();
    String gameObjectName();
    void isActionValid(String action);
    void viewActions();
}
```

I have the following abstract class that implements the above interface.

```
package gameprobjectpackage;

public abstract class Weapon implements IGameObject {
//Left out getters/setters to keep it simple
private String gameOjectID;
private String gameObjectName;
private int damage;

public Weapon(String gameOjectID, String gameObjectName,int damage) {
    super();
    this.gameOjectID = gameOjectID;
    this.gameObjectName = gameObjectName;
    this.damage = damage;
}
```

I've come across a few posts that suggest downcasting should be avoided. I understand why, BUT, my question is what do I do if I need to access a method that is specific to a sub class. For example:

```
public class ChargeGun extends Weapon {


private String [] chargeGunActions;

public ChargeGun(String gameOjectID, String gameObjectName, int damage) {
    super(gameOjectID, gameObjectName, damage);

        chargeGunActions = new String [3];
        chargeGunActions[0] = "Charge and Fire";
        chargeGunActions[1] = "Release";
        chargeGunActions[2] = "Drop Gun";
}

//This method is only meant for gun, and this type of gun is the only one in my game.  
//This method, I don't belive should be in the abstract method weapon, because NOT every weapon is a gun.

public void reloadGun()
{

}
```

I store in in an interventory hashmap like so:

```
Map<String,IGameObject> inventory = new HashMap<String,IGameObject>();
```

When I retrieve it, I will get an `IGameObject`, how do I properly cast it, so that I can access the method in `ChargeGun`?

Comment: I don't see any other way to do this without downcasting. You could disguise it as something else, such as creating a InventoryMap class that has methods to retrieve only maps of specific types or the objects already downcasted, perhaps cleaning your code a little bit. But under the hood it is still downcasting.

Comment: Thanks, just out of curiosity, how would I clean it up ?

Comment: You probably should split your inventory, because what about other items like consumables etc. they all have different specific class methods

Comment: @Nexusfactor implement a `InventoryMap` class with a method `#getItems(Class<?> clazz)`, so you can retrieve a `Map<ChargeGun>` by calling `inventory.getItems(ChargeGun.class)`. With your newly created map of guns, you can do whatever you want. The downcasting would happen inside the `getItems()` method. This only makes sense if you plan to do a lot of things at once with objects of the same class. Otherwise, implement specific getters like `#getGun(String key)`. Just be careful with the desired behavior if a key matches an object that is not a gun.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) which frees you from casting. The idea is simple : You have an inventory of IGameObject which would have a method accept(GameObjectVisitor v) which directly calls v.visit(this). In your GameObjectVisitor, you just have to implement visit methods for each implementations : For example visit(Chargegun g), visit(Sword s), etc...

To explain it another way, it's like the principle of a boomerang : The GameObjectVisitor calls item.accept(this), and the Item implement accept(GameObjectVisitor g) with a simple g.visit(this).

By doing this, the Visitor has multiple visit methods for each implementation and can do specific stuffs without having to cast/using instanceof.

Comment: With this pattern, could I still access the method only available to ChargeGun, the reload method?

Comment: Yes, because in the visit(ChargeGun chargeGun) that you declare in your IGameObjectVisitor, you have declared the paramter as a ChargeGun and thus all the specific methods are available.